# Probability of selecting the largest ball from an urn of 20 balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, solution-verification

We randomly select 4 balls from an urn containing 20 with replacement (select 1 ball, replace it, select again, so on..) and let $X$ be the random variable whose value is the largest number ball selected of the 4 selected balls. Find the probability that $X$ takes on each of its possible values.

My attempt:
We can think of the outcomes counted in $P_X(k)$ as having one ball be the $k$-valued ball (which can be done in $1$ way) and then selecting $3$ more balls from among the ones numbered $1, 2, 3, \dots, k$ (which can be done in $k^3$ ways). The total outcomes of selecting $4$ balls with replacement is $20^4$. Thus,

$P_X(k) = \frac{k^3}{20^4}$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots, 20$.

Does this look right?

Comment: Try the same argument in which "20" is replaced by, say, "2" or "3", and see if you like the answers.

Comment: @JBL I knew my answer was wrong right after I made a simulation and got way different answers. But I don't know where in my reasoning I went wrong.

Comment: $$(Y_k)_{1\leq k \leq m}\textrm{ IID s.t. }Y_1\sim \textrm{Uniform}\{1,2,...,n\}$$

$$P(\max_{1\leq k\leq m}Y_k\leq x)=P(\cap_{1\leq k \leq m}\{Y_k\leq x\})=\bigg(\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}\bigg)^m,x\geq 0$$

Comment: I would suggest the same thing I did before: choose a small example (like where "20" is replaced by "2" or "3", and perhaps also replacing "4" with say "2" or "3"), so that you can  explore what is happening.

Comment: @Snoop do we really need such a complicated looking thing to explain the solution to this seemingly simple problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accounting for permutations and multiple balls taking the maximum value. You can compute this as the probability of $P(A_k\setminus A_{k-1})$, where $A_k$ is the event of extracting four balls, each of value at most $k$. Then $P(A_k)=k^4/20^4$, $P(A_k\setminus A_{k-1})=P(A_k)-P(A_{k-1})=(k^4-(k-1)^4)/20^4$.

Comment: Very nicely explained thanks